# What's wrong with this Intent?

Tags: java, android

What I am trying to do is, when the user chooses this option, my Android app runs an intent. The intent calls for the camera of the Android device, and the camera takes a picture, and then saves the file into the directory named posense.

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName() + File.separatorChar + "posense";
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
File photo = new File(path);
Intent newintent = intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
imageuri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
startActivityForResult(newintent, 1);
```

Comment: Some description regarding the problem might be useful.

Comment: Simply put, the picture does not go into my desired directory posense.

Comment: try: File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "posense");    And check if you have the right to write the file there.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have correct permissions in your manifest. They would be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I don't think that the `CAMERA` permissions is needed. Just the called activity needs the `CAMERA` permission.